# Multiplying top and bottom by $ \cos (x) $ to solve integral?

Tags: calculus

Please take a look at this integral. Why is this method not a valid way of solving this integral?

$\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{\sin (x) \cos(x)} \ dx = \int \frac{\cos (x)}{\sin (x) \cos^2(x)} \ dx =  \int \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin (x) (1-\sin^2 (x))} \ dx = \int \frac{1}{u(1-u^2)} \ du$

And by utilizing partial fractions we arrive at

$ \displaystyle \int \frac{1}{\sin (x) \cos(x)} \ dx = \ln(|\sin (x)|)+\frac{1}{2}\ln(|1-\sin(x)|)-\frac{1}{2}\ln(|1+\sin (x)|)$

I am guessing the incorrect step was multiplying top and bottom of the fraction $\frac{1}{\sin (x) \cos(x)}$ by $\cos x$. But **why** is this step incorrect? I have not changed the value of the function since it was just a multiplication by 1 and in addition to that I do not believe that any domain issues arise or division by zero issues arise. As we have already started with a function that has both $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ in the dominator, we then assume this function would only be defined for values when $\sin(x) \not= 0 $ and $ \cos(x) \not = 0 $ therefore multiplying by $\frac{\cos (x)}{\cos(x)}$ shouldn't cause any further issues?

Comment: Alternatively, you can use $\sin x \cos x=  \frac{1}{2} \sin 2x$ and $\int \csc x \ dx = -\ln |\cot x + \csc x| + C$. This only helps if you remember the trick or use a table of integrals: your way with partial fractions is perfectly fine.

Comment: Once you see the partial fractions error, then you just need to see why the expression is equivalent to $-\ln(\cot x)$ (which is the antiderivative of $\frac 2{\sin 2x} = \frac 1{\sin x \cos x}$), by using the usual $\ln$ laws.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done the partial fractions incorrectly. It should be:

$$\frac{1}{u(1-u^2)} = \frac{1}{u} - \frac{1}{2(u+1)} \color{red}{-} \frac{1}{2(u-1)}$$

Comment: Oh shoot! Yes, my bad. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Would there be any instances where this type of multiplying by 1 with trig functions could cause any issues? In all the instructional videos that I have watched, this type of multiplication is avoided.

Comment: No, it's perfectly fine. In fact, it's not much of a problem when you divide by something (like $\cos x$) as there is only a pointwise discontinuity which does not affect the area. Integration has many less strings attached than differentiation: you can integrate more functions than you can differentiate.